# Docker for Windows exe fails inside Container

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

In-House developed .exe file is failing in container, it prints no error, and just returns the exit code -1073741515. The exe seems to be running fine on other machines. I understand this error code means it's missing a DLL File or Library but I don't which one.

It's a windowsservercore based container. Running no other application except this .exe, and running it on Command Prompt, although Powershell also return same exit code.

1. I took a dump of it using dumpbin tool (which comes with Visual Studio), to check which DLL files it uses, and my container is also having all those DLLs
2. I tried Dr. Memory tools like drmemory.exe and it says the `WARNING: libraries needed by the application are missing.  Check that it runs successfully on its own and check that all needed libraries are in its directory or on the PATH.`

I am running out of options to troubleshoot. How can I find what is causing this .exe to fail or any missing dependency?

Comment: The best way is to reach out to the .exe developers and ask for help. They might be able to tell you how to turn on logging or tell you what required dependncies are or provide other ways to diagnose their software.

Comment: [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) should show the paths of the dependent libraries and you can check if the right dlls are being loaded.

Comment: Finally, how did you handle this problem? If you find what files are missing, do you need to copy them manually? Is there any elegant way to resolve this?